# CV: Student work as education or work experience

Tags: resume

During my Bachelor and Master studies, I worked as student assistant at the university. The first job was teaching assistance (leading exercise courses, homework/exam grading). The second was research assistant (implementation of algorithms and experiment setups). I graduated some years ago and am working since then.

Initially, I listed my university jobs in the category "work experience". However, a CV counselor of my university gave me the advice to list them in the section "education" and I listened to her advice.

Now, I am preparing a new CV targeted at *international* audiences (which usually means Anglo-American) and after having reviewed some guides and example CVs online (e.g., [this](https://zety.com/blog/python-developer-resume-example)), the "education" section seems quite condensed, whereas intern work is listed as actual work experience.

What is the usual approach to include relevant student work experience in the CV when there is already some "real" work experience present?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Thanks for your confirmation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd put it down as work experience, and I'm somewhat surprised at the CV counselor suggesting otherwise. Just because the job was in the education *sector* doesn't make it any less of a job.

Education on the CV is for activities where you're receiving education (i.e. taking a degree or a course).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess, it may come from the fact that in Germany, internships. apprenticeships and student jobs aren't really regarded as work experience, because it's usually guided work, i.e., someone will tell you how to do what - even though this doesn't apply to all such jobs.